# Testimonial star rating in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have `stars` column in my `testimonials` table where is gets numbers between `1` to `5` now i want to show stars depend on the number that saves in that column. For example if number is `2` show `2` stars and if is `5` show `5` stars like that.

I know it can be done trough my model but not sure how to do it.

> PS: I want to use font-awesome `fa fa-star` to show stars in my blade.

any idea?

## UPDATE

Maybe I need to explain little more, here is my table [screenshot](https://ibb.co/nA4Dnx) As you see there is only `1` column named `stars` and it gets numbers between 1-5.

Comment: Just make 5 images and load them based on rating what's the problem :D

Comment: @SagarGautam that's not the clean way bro, i'm more looking for the way to loop my numbers and show font-icons base on those numbers.\

Comment: Thats good, with out using font awesome it's difficult then

Answer (score 1):

**Try this in your view:**

```
@for ($i = 0; $i < $star; $i++)
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
@endfor
```

More on [Laravel blade loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#loops).

Comment: how is that different to my answer? i fail to understand

Comment: @HamzaMohamed Suppose in a column there are 5 entries. each entry having a value. My code loops as many times as the value but your code loops as many times as the entries in that column. OP said he has a stars column which stores "value" between 1-5, So you need to loop based on the star value of each column and not how many entries are there in the star column. Get it?

Comment: thanks for answer somehow your code just make my pages loading without showing anything . I also updated my question please check it.